# Getting error while sending mail?

Tags: asp.net

when i am sending mail in my web application i am getting this erro.

I AM GETTING THIS ERROR. The element may only appear once in this section. (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\web.config line 64)

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="webmail.example.com" port="25" userName="info@example.com" password="asdf" defaultCredentials="false"/>
            <network host="webmail.yyy.com" port="25" userName="info@yyy.com" password="asdf12" defaultCredentials="false"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Please paste us what the text is on line 64.

Comment: have you had a look at web.config line 64? might there be an element there, that may only appear once in its section?

Comment: my web config i hav two network tags in mailsetting like this <system.net>  <mailSettings>  <smtp>  <network host="webmail.xxx.com" port="25" userName="info@xxx.com" password="asdf" defaultCredentials="false"/>  <network host="webmail.yyy.com" port="25" userName="info@yyy.com" password="asdf12" defaultCredentials="false"/>  </smtp>  </mailSettings>  </system.net>   
This is my web.config code

Comment: based on that, what would you *guess* that the error message is trying to tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have duplicated an element in your web.config file. If you have added something to the config to enable or help your email, then you have likely added the same entry twice by accident, or duplicated an entry that was already there to change its value.

Perhaps something like:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="mailFromAddress" value="me@thing.com"/>
    <add key="mailFromAddress" value="me@thing.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Mr. Xan actually in my web config i hav two network tags in mailsetting like this 

<system.net>
      <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
          <network host="webmail.xxx.com" port="25" userName="info@xxx.com" password="asdf"  defaultCredentials="false"/>
 <network host="webmail.yyy.com" port="25" userName="info@yyy.com" password="asdf12"  defaultCredentials="false"/>
        </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
    </system.net>

Answer (score 0):

you might one to post what is line 64 of your web.config. Microsoft went to a lot of effort to help you debug your problem by giving you a line number. Might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

examine your web.config @ line 64, then search for that element elsewhere in your web.config and delete it.

apparently the schema prohibits multiple `network` elements. remove one and see what happens.